# Delete custom meta

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

My custom meta box correctly saves my file upload. When the user wants to clear the field, they can click delete and I want to delete that meta data of the file URL only. How can I assign the meta_id correctly to the `$meta_id` variable in my function?

[image]

And I need to assign this `meta_id`, for example, to `$meta_id`

[image]

Here is the function creating this box as well as the save function.

```
function wp_custom_attachment() {

wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce');

$html = '<p class="description">';
    $html .= 'Upload your PDF here.';
$html .= '</p>';
$html .= '<input type="file" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" value="" size="25" />';

$pdf = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true);

if($pdf['url']){
    $html .=  '<p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Current file: ' .$pdf['url'] . '</p>';
    } 

$delete_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'delete-meta_' . $meta_id );
$html.=get_submit_button( __( 'Delete' ), "delete:wp_custom_attachment:meta-{$meta_id}::_ajax_nonce=$delete_nonce deletemeta", "deletemeta[{$meta_id}]", false, array( 'tabindex' => '6' ) );
$html.=wp_nonce_field( 'change-meta', '_ajax_nonce', false, false );

echo $html;

} // end wp_custom_attachment

function save_custom_meta_data($id) {

/* --- security verification --- */
if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_custom_attachment_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
  return $id;
} // end if

if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
  return $id;
} // end if

if('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
  if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
    return $id;
  } // end if
} else {
    if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
        return $id;
    } // end if
} // end if
/* - end security verification - */

// Make sure the file array isn't empty
if(!empty($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'])) {

    // Setup the array of supported file types. In this case, it's just PDF.
    $supported_types = array('application/pdf');

    // Get the file type of the upload
    $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name']));
    $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

    // Check if the type is supported. If not, throw an error.
    if(in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types)) {

        // Use the WordPress API to upload the file
        $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name']));

        if(isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
            wp_die('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error']);
        } else {
            update_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);     
        } // end if/else

    } else {
        wp_die("The file type that you've uploaded is not a PDF.");
    } // end if/else

} // end if

} // end save_custom_meta_data
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta_data');
```

Comment: Yes, you should combine the CRUD functions (Create, Read, Update, Delete) in your callback handler.

Comment: Post your save handling function as well, please.

Comment: what's $meta_id in this context? it isn't initialized on this block of code. are you saving the uploaded as a regular attachment, or just a plain file upload?

Comment: @yivi I've added the save function above. I hope that helps. Thank you for having a look!

Answer (score 0):

I found [a function to get the Meta ID by Meta Key](https://wpseek.com/blog/2010/how-to-get-the-meta-id-by-meta-key/80/). This allowed me to correctly assign my $meta_ID variable, and now the delete ajax button works perfectly.

No need to update the save function at all.

```
function get_mid_by_key( $post_id, $meta_key ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $mid = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key = %s", $post_id, $meta_key) );
  if( $mid != '' )
    return (int)$mid;

  return false;
}

function wp_custom_attachment() {

wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce');

$html = '<p class="description">';
    $html .= 'Upload your PDF here.';
$html .= '</p>';
$html .= '<input type="file" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" value="" size="25" />';

$pdf = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true);

if($pdf['url']){
    $html .=  '<p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Current file: ' .$pdf['url'] . '</p>';
    } 

$meta_id=get_mid_by_key( get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment' );

$delete_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'delete-meta_' . $meta_id );
$html.=get_submit_button( __( 'Delete' ), "delete:wp_custom_attachment:meta-{$meta_id}::_ajax_nonce=$delete_nonce deletemeta", "deletemeta[{$meta_id}]", false, array( 'tabindex' => '6' ) );
$html.=wp_nonce_field( 'change-meta', '_ajax_nonce', false, false );

echo $html;

} // end wp_custom_attachment
```